# Tell cargo to link to external library in the right order (i.e. after stdlib)

Tags: rust, embedded, rust-cargo

I have an embedded target for which I can build a simple Rust application. For also building a unit test executable I need to link to an additional static embedded-OS libary (called *libbsd*) which provides the implementation for `poll` needed for the test harness of the stdlib.

My problem is that the `-lbsd` argument is put at the wrong position in the final link command, so I get an undefined reference error. If I run the same linker command manually, but put the `-lbsd` flag at the end everything works fine. How do I tell `cargo` where to place this library?

So far I tried to add `println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=bsd");` to `build.rs` or adding it to the `RUSTFLAGS` environment variable, but without success.

It would be fine to add this libary also to the general build. The main thing is to control that it appears after `libstd`.

Interestingly, it works if I set `RUSTFLAGS=-lbsd` and build with `cargo test -Z build-std=std,panic_abort`. My guess is that because the flags are also set when rebuilding libstd locally that the references are already resolved when finally linking the test binary?